# Unexpected character is displayed in the textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a very simple .NET program.  It's just to write a string to the textbox.  There is a strange character appearing at the end of my string.

[image]

This happens only on my 32-bit XP box.  The same program works fine on another 64bit Windows 2008 machine.

The program is as simple as this.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Hello\n\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    }
```

I know it's odd to add \0 at the end of the string and I can trim them before applying to the textbox.  The textbox is set to allow multi-line.

Just out of curiousity, does anybody know where the problem comes from?  Both machines got .NET 3.5 SP1 installed.  Both of them are set to have the same regional settings.  I doubt if it is related to 32-bit or 64-bit.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @DBM and @Andrew.  The strange character is coming from \n but nothing to do with \0.  Now, it sounds like Windows 2008 can understand both \r\n and \n.  Can anybody confirm that?

Comment: What if you do `\r\n` instead of `\n`?

Comment: @Alex you got it.  \r\n doesn't have any issue on both XP box and 2008.  Do you know what's going on?  Both of them have .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: Check out this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2581325/174682)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard end-of-line sequence in Windows is `\r\n`.  The text box isn't recognising the `\n` as a new-line without the preceding carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: Got it. I think you are right that I should use \r\n instead. It sounds like Windows 2008 just happens to understand \n but XP doesn't.  Can anyone confirm that Windows 2008 support \n?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Environment.NewLine` instead of \r\n, in general.

In the way of explanation: Environment.NewLine will contain the proper sequence of escape characters for whatever platform the application is running in. On Windows, it's \r\n, but *nix (if I recall correctly) uses \n only.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you that I should use `Environment.NewLine` too.  I think my intention for the question was to find out why they behave differently in Windows 2008 and Windows XP rather than making the strange character disappeared.